# JavaScript-PDF Dropdown-Menu

Tags: javascript, pdf

so I am a total javascript newbie. I am currently working on a PDF, quit simple task I guess but I can't figure it out.

So I am having two dropdown's.

1st with values: "HR Business", "HR Consulting", "Recruiting"

2nd with: "Senior HR Business Partner", "HR Business Partner", "HR Admin", "Junior Consultant", "Junior Talent Marketing", "Senior Sourcing"

If in the 1st dropdown "HR Business" is chosen the 2nd should only display "Senior HR Business Partner, HR Business Partner"

If in the 1st dropdown "HR Consulting" is chosen the 2nd should only display "HR Admin, Junior Consultant"

and so on.

So what I have until now is.

```
if(event.value=="HR Business") {

getField("Senior HR Business Partner").display = display.visible;
getField("HR Business Partner").display = display.visible;
getField("HR Admin").display = display.hidden;
getField("Junior Consultant").display = display.hidden;
getField("Junior Talent Marketing").display = display.hidden;
getField("Senior Sourcing").display = display.hidden;
}

else if( for HR Consulting){

getField("Senior HR Business Partner").display = display.hidden;
getField("HR Business Partner").display = display.hidden;
getField("HR Admin").display = display.visible;
getField("Junior Consultant").display = display.visible;
getField("Junior Talent Marketing").display = display.hidden;
getField("Senior Sourcing").display = display.hidden;
}



else {for Recruiting}()
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to scrap what you have. The display property of a field has nothing to do with the items in a list. What you want to do is use the value of the first dropdown to set the item list of the second. Without the form, I can't really give you the corrected code. I suggest you take a look at the link then start over. 
http://khkonsulting.com/2017/01/learning-to-program-javascript-for-adobe-acrobat/

Comment: I completely reworked it and it works now. Thanks for the hint.